# Error "URL parsing failed" in Nuxt.js2 when using the command "npm run build"

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxt 2 when I use `npm run dev`, there are no errors or problems
but when I use `npm run build`, the following error occurs:

[image]

I deleted some packages, removed individual pages and components, and rebuilt google search but it had no effect.

Comment: Check the codes where you used `parse-url`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you have `target: 'static'` or `'server'`? Also, do you use SASS? Sharing us your `nuxt.config.js` or any relevant file where you're parsing an URL may be useful here.

Comment: Please edit your question rather.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you need to downgrade node.js to version 12

Comment: Have to downvote that one. Node v14 is dead, so use either v16 or 18. v12 is a long dead one, bad idea to recommend this one.

Answer (score 0):

### The issue is related to Telemetry.

> Nuxt collects anonymous telemetry data about general usage. This helps us to accurately gauge Nuxt feature usage and customization across all our users.

Resolved via **disabling** telemetry in `nuxt.config`. Or in `nuxt.config.ts` if you're using **Nuxt 3**.

*nuxt.config*

```
export default {
  telemetry: false
}
```

*nuxt.config.ts*

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  telemetry: false
})
```

Hope this helps!

---

This issue **doesn't** occur to me with a **freshly-created** Nuxt project. But when I clone an existing project, or move the project to some other directory - I start getting these errors.

I can't seem to find docs (or some hacks) to establish Telemetry for a 'copied' project - so, at the moment, the only way to get over this problem is to disable Telemetry.